# Let $H_i (i \in I)$ be a family of subgroups of $G$. Does $\bigcap \mathrm{core}(H_i) = \mathrm{core}(\bigcap H_i)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $H \leq G$, then we define $\mathrm{core}(H) = \bigcap\limits_{g \in G} (gHg^{-1})$. It seems to me that $\mathrm{core}(\bigcap H_i ) \subseteq \bigcap \mathrm{core}(H_i )$, but I'm not sure of the converse. Any clues?

Comment: Might it help to try to frame the problem in terms of group actions?

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht Yes, actually, since that is the context I'm working in.

Comment: The intersection of the cores is a normal subgroup contained in each $H_i$, so it is contained in the core of their intersection. (The core in $G$ of $H$ can be equivalently defined as the largest normal subgroup of $G$ that is contained in $H$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us write $H^g$ for $gHg^{-1}$. Note that for all $i$ we have $\bigcap_{i \in I} H_i \subseteq H_i$, and hence for any $g \in G$, $(\bigcap_{i \in I} H_i)^g \subseteq H_i^g$. This implies $core_G(\bigcap_{i \in I} H_i) \subseteq core_G(H_i)$ for all $i$. So $core_G(\bigcap_{i \in I} H_i) \subseteq \bigcap_{i \in I} core_G(H_i)$. 
Conversely, $core_G(H_i) \subseteq H_i$ by definition and hence $\bigcap_{i \in I} core_G(H_i) \subseteq \bigcap_{i \in I} H_i$. But $\bigcap_{i \in I} core_G(H_i) \unlhd G$, since every $core_G(H_i) \unlhd G$. And this shows that $\bigcap_{i \in I} core_G(H_i) \subseteq core_G(\bigcap_{i \in I} H_i)$. 
So indeed $\bigcap_{i \in I} core_G(H_i) = core_G(\bigcap_{i \in I}H_i)$.$\square$